# operations with vectors and xml file for SVM on c++

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, svm

i'm writing a code for SVM detection using Opencv. Actualy, for the training data, i've two matrix (positive and negative features) creating by:

```
const size_t N=12;
std::vector<std::array<int,N>> matrixForTrainingDataPos;
std::vector<std::array<int,N>> matrixForTrainingDataNeg;
```

populated with 12 features for each image. I've 100 positive images and 140 negative images and then matrixForTrainingDataPos is [100][12] and matrixForTrainingDataNeg[140][12]. Now i have to concatenate them to get:

```
 float trainingData[240][12] = {--------};
 Mat trainingDataMat(240, 12, CV_32FC1, trainingData);
```

I tried with some operation as pusk_back but I did not succeed.  I am , however, managed to build an array of 240 elements for the labeling: 100 with 1 and 140 with -1 using two for cicle. Next step is save a trainingData on xml file so that once launched the program if there is no file creates it , avoiding all the processing of trainingData if you have already made
can you help me? 
tanks!

Comment: Can you show how you tried to copy the vectors into the array and what issues/errors you had with that?

Comment: i've used                                                                                                                                                                                                                        `std::array<int, 12> findFeatures(std::vector<double>segments);
std::vector<double>segments=findBuildings(image);
std::array<int, 12> found=findFeatures(segments);
matrixForTrainingDataNeg.push_back(found);` the same code for matrixForTrainingDataPos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < matrixForTrainingDataPos.size(); i++)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
   {
       trainingData[count][j] = matrixForTrainingDataPos[i][j];
   }
   count++;
}

/* copy negative sample matrix data */
```

Comment: `trainingData` is declared as `float trainingData[240][12]`, or if size of training vectors is not known, it can be done so using `new`

Comment: @BeyelerStudios thanks for pointing it out, updated the code :)

Answer (score 0):

it works. But the compiler returned an exception for me so I had to declare ad unsigned the i j variables: `for (unsigned i=0......`

for my second question? how i save and load this matrix on xml file, on first passage, to avoid in the next steps to be recalculated?

Comment: If you really want to load and save from a xml file i would suggest, you use some third party library (e.g. tinyxml) or check if opencv itself provides, xml serialization functions. Otherwise i would suggest just save them in an csv file which is easier to implement.